# Difference in invoking through Delegates and Events C#

Tags: c#, events, delegates

What is the difference?

**Using Delegate**

```
public delegate void TestDelegate();
public TestDelegate delObj = SomeMethod;

public void SomeMethod()
{
    .....
}

public void Test()
{
    if(delObj != null)
        delObj();
}
```

**Using Event**

```
public delegate void TestDelegate();
public event TestDelegate EdelObj += SomeMethod;

public void SomeMethod()
{
    .....
}

public void Test()
{
    if(EdelObj != null)
        EdelObj();
}
```

Both seem to work. Can anybody explain what is the difference and which scenario should we use one of the above?

Edit
Chaining works for both. Sorry it was a mistake from my end.

Thanks
 Nishant

Comment: chaining works on both as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An event declaration is really just a special kind of property that's used to expose a delegate.  Instead of get and set accessors, though, it creates add and remove ones.  Normally they're implemented automatically, but if you desire you can add custom behavior:

```
private MyEventHandler handler;
public event MyEventHandler MyEvent {
    add {
        handler += value;
        Trace.WriteLine("MyEvent handler attached.");
    }
    remove {
        handler -= value;
        Trace.WriteLine("MyEvent handler removed.");
    }
}
```

This does two things.  First, since events are properties they can be included in interfaces.  Second, since MyEvent does not return a value, the delegate is completely encapsulated and only the object that owns it can invoke it.  Other ways of exposing delegates result in a delegate that can be invoked by just about anyone.

Beyond that bit of special language support, the other major difference between events and delegates is a convention rather than a language or framework feature: Events are expected to follow [certain patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w369ty8x.aspx), such as making sure that the delegate on which the event is based follows the pattern established by the [EventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler.aspx) delegate.

Generally, events are preferred whenever the semantics are that of an object notifying anyone who's interested about a change in its stage.  Delegates are preferred in situations where you want others to be able to define behavior by supplying their own procedure, such as the delegate parameters that are taken by many of the extension methods on IEnumerable that are used in LINQ.

Comment: Thanks. I feel I am getting there. But still have a couple of doubts looming in my mind. I just tried invoking an event from another class and it failed unlike for delegates. So that is one difference. But I am unable to understand the statement you have given to support this behavior "since MyEvent does not return a value, the delegate is completely encapsulated and only the object that owns it can invoke it". Can you please throw a bit more light on to it?

Comment: It works out that way because the `add` and `remove` accessors in an event both work more like the `set` accessor in a property:  They take an argument (`value`) and use it to modify the field that the event covers, and can only be used when the event or property is the target of an assignment statement.  There's no equivalent to a `get` accessor in an event, and that makes it impossible to evaluate an event in order to get at the delegate that backs it.  And since you can't get the delegate through the event, you can't invoke it through the event.

Answer (score 2):

It works exactly same. If you use

```
public event EventHandler SomeEvent;
```

the C# compiler does (simplified code):

```
private EventHandler SomeEventField;
public void add_SomeEvent( EventHandler handler) {
    this.SomeEventField = (EventHandler)Delegate.Combine(this.SomeEvent, handler);
}
public void remove_SomeEvent( EventHandler ) {
   this.SomeEventField = (EventHandler)Delegate.Remove(this.SomeEvent, handler);
}
```

The method `add_SomeEvent` is called when you use `SomeEvent += ...` and the `remove_SomeEvent` is called when you use `SomeEvent -= ...`.

However in both cases there are used same delegates.

Comment: The default event add/remove accessors also lock on 'this' to provide thread-safety when updating the underlying delegate.  This is not a great practice (since 'this' is publicly visible), but it was chosen by the C# designers as a reasonable compromise to prevent a common 'gotcha' when using events.  Another side effect of the way events are wrapped in this way is an outside class cannot retrieve or invoke the underlying delegate; only the class defining the event can invoke the event's delegate.

Comment: @Dan Bryant: Thanks for note. I skiped locking for simplicity. As I wrote - it's "simplified code".

Comment: @TcLs, understood; I just thought it was worth mentioning, as it's a fairly significant implementation detail that can have unintended visible consequences (it can be used to create a baffling deadlock, for instance.)

Answer (score 1):

It is not delegate vs event, an event is a kind-of property around a delegate.

In general you should always use the second scenario because in the first `public TestDelegate delObj` is a public field, breaking Encapsulation.

You use events in the interface of a class, delegates as parameters to methods.

Answer (score 1):

It's effectively a property wrapper around the event.

The main difference is that you can't invoke/raise the event from outside the class, whereas you can invoke the public delegate.

Chaining (+=) is no different for delegates and events.

Answer (score 0):

C# has a lot of constructs that don't add anything new to the language, but are simply syntactic sugar for a construct, because the construct requires some pattern of code which is tiresome to type every time over and over again. For example the using statement is equivalent of a try-finally block with a call to the dispose method, and properties are just syntactic sugar for an get and/or set method.

In a similar way events are just syntactic sugar for a delegate field. There are some subtle differences however, which others have mentioned. Since a public field isn't recommended, the delegate would have to be encapsulated and a nice way of doing that is with an event. And (as Mark mentions) the event is only invokable from inside of the class.

I usually choose between delegate field and event based on what I conceptually think the field or event should represent. If it represents something anyone would want to be notified of, I'd recommend the event. Otherwise if it represents for example a function to acquire a result, I'd use a delegate field.

Comment: Events are not syntactic sugar for delegate fields.  They're syntactic sugar for `AddEventHandler()` and `RemoveEventHandler()` methods.